# Input Number - max constraint validation not working

Tags: javascript, html, validation, input

I have an input field `number` that you can see on snippet below, this seems to work but there is a bug.

When you insert 89, it works and returns the max value as it is supposed to.

But if the first digit is under 7, it doesn't work (any number under 69). It only compares the first digit and not the final digit.

How can I use it the right way?

Thank you!

```html
<input type="number" name="teste" id="teste"
       value="0" min="0" max="7" 
       onchange="javascript: if (this.value > this.max) this.value = this.max;" />
```

Comment: Why do you have an onchange handler there at all? 
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_max.asp

Comment: @Dellirium Please do not link to or use w3schools.

Comment: @ChrisG is it against stackoverflow policy? I do not use w3s however for something as simple as input max, it does convey the message and it was the #1 google result, thus I linked it.

Comment: @Dellirium It needs to go away from the #1 spot, which is one of the reasons you shouldn't link to it. It's not against policy, but against good taste at the very least.

Comment: @Dellirium please [read this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280478/why-not-w3schools-com)

Comment: I mean, I completely agree and pretty much never use it myself, MDN is a lot better, but when first starting out it was too technical, w3s was more newb-friendly.

Comment: `onchange="if (+this.value > +this.max) this.value = this.max;"`

Comment: The `javascript:` label is useless here

Answer (score 2):

Maybe convert value to integer before comparison
like this:

```html
   <input type="number" name="teste" id="teste" value="0" min="0" max="7" onchange="javascript: if (parseInt(this.value) > this.max) this.value = this.max;" />
```

Comment: Exactly what I need. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

HTML attributes can only contain text (no other types) so you are doing [lexicographical order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order). Please compare:

```js
console.log("27" > "7");
console.log(27 > 7);
```

Since it isn't very useful to sort numbers alphabetically, you can [extract numbers from strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt):

```js
console.log("27", typeof "27");
console.log(parseInt("27", 10), typeof parseInt("27", 10));
```

Nowadays, second argument (radix or base) *should* default to 10 in most cases but setting is explicitly avoids surprises.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the code: `if (this.value > this.max) this.value = this.max;`

In the function, the values of the *input* and the *max* are used and compared as text (or string data type). Your intention is to compare numbers. The example does that:

The HTML:

```
<body>

    Result: <p id="result">0</p>

    <input type="number" name="teste" id="teste" 
           value="0" min="0" max="7" 
           onchange="test(this)" />

    <script src="test.js"></script>

</body>
```

*test.js:*

```
function test(elmnt) {

    console.log(typeof elmnt.value); // this returns "string"
    console.log(typeof elmnt.max);   // this returns "string"

    // convert string numbers to integer numbers
    let intVal = parseInt(elmnt.value);
    let maxInt = parseInt(elmnt.max);

    console.log("Input: " + intVal);

    if (intVal > maxInt) {
        intVal = maxInt;
    }

    console.log("Result: " + intVal);
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = intVal;
}
```